# How compare data from database?

Tags: iphone, sql, database, compiler-construction

I have create a database. In my view i am checking provided dat is already exist or not. If exist then retrun Yes otherwise no. for this i have use this code..

```
 +(BOOL)compareDataInDB:(NSString *)Start_text EndAddress:(NSString *)End_text Categories:(NSString *)Category_text{


BOOL flag=FALSE;

if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
    //int LastId="select Max(place_id) from Places";
    //      NSLog(@"%i",LastId);
    const char *sql = "select * from Places where Start_text = Start_text  and End_text = End_text and Category_text = Category_text";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int rtnVal = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if( rtnVal == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            flag=TRUE;

        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
sqlite3_close(db);

if(flag==TRUE)
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
```

}

on button action i have use this code

```
-(IBAction)Find{
  BOOL tmp=[GlobalClass compareDataInDB:txtstart.text EndAddress:txtend.text   Categories:txtCategory.text];
    if(tmp)
    [GlobalClass storeDataInDB:txtstart.text EndAddress:txtend.text Categories:txtCategory.text];
    else 
        NSLog(@"exsit data in database");
}
```

Now problem is that it always return no. What is error in this code? And How make compression in data  from data base?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: if(flag==TRUE) return YES  ?  Is this a joke?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat What is error in this?

Comment: flag is only TRUE or FALSE, then why don't you just return flag instead of comparing it? That's the "wrong" part

Comment: No need to check flag==true. just assign flag = YES or NO and return the flag that would be sufficient to ur case.

Comment: Did any of following answer helped ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use following code for SQL Statement.

```
NSString *tempSQL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from Places where Start_text = '%@'  and End_text = '%@' and Category_text = '%@'", Start_text, Start_text, Category_text];
const char *sql = [tempSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[tempSQL release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+(BOOL)compareDataInDB:(NSString *)Start_text EndAddress:(NSString *)End_text Categories:NSString *)Category_text
{       
    BOOL flag=NO;

    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        //int LastId="select Max(place_id) from Places";
        //      NSLog(@"%i",LastId);
        const char *sql = "select * from Places where Start_text = Start_text  and End_text = End_text and Category_text = Category_text";
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        int rtnVal = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
        if( rtnVal == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
           sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [Start_text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [End_text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [Category_text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                flag=YES;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return flag;
    }
```